# What's the difference of mark-sweep-compact vs mark-compact?

Tags: garbage-collection

if `gc` use `mark-sweep-compact` algorithm, why need `sweep` while compact memory, because compact already remain continuous space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `mark-sweep-compact` algorithm , only have `mark-sweep` and `mark-compact`; but sometimes you can combine both at different stage , eg : cms collector .